# Prolog - bagof - case of no results

Tags: prolog

I have activity-users relations:

```
% Signature: activity(Name,Day)/2
% Purpose: describe an activity at the country club and the day it takes place
%
activity(swimming,sunday).
activity(ballet,monday).
activity(judu,tuesday).
activity(soccer,wednesday).
activity(art,sunday).
activity(yoga,tuesday).


% Signature: participate(Child_name,Activity)/2
% Purpose: registration details
%
participate(dany,swimming).
participate(dany,ballet).
participate(dana,soccer).
participate(dana,judu).
participate(guy,judu).
participate(shai,soccer).
```

I want to create query to get all the participants of activity.

So I use bagof:
`activity_participants_list(Activity_Name,List) :- ( bagof(X, participate(X,Activity_Name), List)).`

But I want to get List = [] when query: `activity_participants_list(dancing,List)`

So I added `; List = []` to the end of the function but then
when query

`activity_participants_list(A,B)` i also get empty list as an answer
And query `activity_participants_list(A, [])` return true.

I also would like to get yoga with empty list as an answer to `activity_participants_list(A,B)`
What is the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you found, `bagof` fails when the goal has no solutions. This is dumb design, unfortunately. As you also found, `;` is tricky to use. Try not to be tempted to use it.

`findall` works similarly to `bagof`, and it does give an empty list of results if the goal has no solutions:

```
activity_participants(Activity, Participants) :-
    activity(Activity, _),  % we are interested in a concrete activity
    findall(Participant, participate(Participant, Activity), Participants).

?- activity_participants(Activity, Participants).
Activity = swimming,
Participants = [dany] ;
Activity = ballet,
Participants = [dany] ;
Activity = judu,
Participants = [dana, guy] ;
Activity = soccer,
Participants = [dana, shai] ;
Activity = art,
Participants = [] ;
Activity = yoga,
Participants = [].
```

The role of the `activity(Activity, _)` goal is to bind `Activity`, this basically forces `findall` to succeed several times, grouped by activity. If we removed this goal, we wouldn't group by activity, and we would just get a list of all the people participating in any activity:

```
?- activity_participants(Activity, Participants).
Participants = [dany, dany, dana, dana, guy, shai].
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not what I meant. I want to create conecction between specific activity to its participents. For example: results for you query should give us (among the rest): Activity = judu, Participens =[dana, guy] and also - no repetions

Comment: W.r.t. "dumb design": Well, that was deliberate. Do you have a better one? It would at least involve a lot more quantors.

Comment: A better design would succeed with `Instances = []` if `Goal` has no solutions. The current behavior would be trivial to simulate with `bagof_correct(Template, Goal, Instances), Instances \= []` while simulating the correct behavior with current broken bagof would need disjunction with some form of cut. I don't know what quantifiers you mean but I would strike "non-empty" in the semantic description in 8.10.2.1 and change 8.10.2.1 d to something like "..., then if `Instances` unifies with `[]`, then the goal succeeds, else the goal fails".

Comment: You are pointing out a single issue, without realizing the consequences it would have on the remaining construct! In particular, many more quantors would be needed. Just "fixing" this case is not enough! Also note the many desirable properties the current bagof/setof has, in particular w.r.t. monotonicity.

Comment: You're right that I don't realize the consequences you have in mind. Maybe you could open a new question for discussion.